# Unable to reset Border Opacity to 1.0 after a storyboard has run that causes the opacity to fade

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity, storyboard

In the example below, the border has a text block and a button inside. after the button is pressed, the fadeBorder is called and the border and everything in it fades nicely. If I try to call someMethod a 2nd time, the border opacity is still 0, and I can't see my border/message/button. I tried to set it back to one by doing myBorder.Opacity=1;  This does not have any effect on the opacity, it's still set to 0 after this line. Is there a trick to resetting my Border opacity back to 1.0 after a storyboard has completed? I also tried setting a double var to 1.0, then assign that var to the border opacity, that did not have an effect either.

```
public void someMethod(string message) {
    myTextBlock.Text = message;
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myTextBlock);
    Ect... with Button Control and alignment of controls
    fadeBorder();

protected void fadeBorder() {
    var fade = new DoubleAnimation() {
        From = 1,
        To = 0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.secondsToFade),
    };

    Storyboard.SetTarget(fade, myBorder);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade, new PropertyPath(Border.OpacityProperty));
    storyBoard.Children.Add(fade);
    storyBoard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx)